# Python 36 - returning data on errors - Exception is almost useless?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, index-error

The basic example is everywhere;

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

...I argue that it is only a hair above absolutely useless when it comes to debugging.

I feel like there's no reason whatsoever to handle exceptions in this way, for debugging, because there's almost no information given at all. At least when it hard-faults it gives you the trace to what caused the problem.

"List Index out of Range" - yeah thanks. I knew that, it's why I caught IndexError!

So is it possible to return the line that caused the exception or any actually useful data? Or is it just for handling known exceptions with known vectors?

Thank you!

Comment: _"I feel like there's no reason whatsoever to handle exceptions in this way, for debugging"_ - I think you're right. It's a lousy tool for debugging, but that's not a surprise since that's not what try/except was designed for. It can be used for debugging of course, but its primary purpose is to catch and handle unexpected run time exceptions. In real world applications you should pretty much never just have a print statement there.

Answer (score 1):

A `try-except` block is used when the developer wants to avoid crashing the program, and either ignore an error or handle an error in a specific way.

I agree with you; printing the error is almost the same as not catching it. Removing the try-except block and taking a look at the stack trace will give you the most information about the error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and opinion, I discovered using the traceback library is pretty great for this. Now I more clearly understand error handling in python.

Answer (score 1):

For the searchers;
You can use the traceback library!

```
import traceback
try:
    print(x)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```